# Pass in Dynamic Formatted Datetime to K8s Container Config

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-cronjob

I have a `CronJob` that runs a process in a container in Kubernetes.

This process takes in a time window that is defined by a `--since` and `--until` flag.  This time window needs to be defined at container start time (when the cron is triggered) and is a function of the current time.  An example running this process would be:

```sh
$ my-process --since=$(date -v -1H +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") --until=$(date -v +1H +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

So for the example above, I would like the time window to be from 1 hour ago to 1 hour in the future.  Is there a way in Kubernetes to pass in a formatted datetime as a command argument to a process?

An example of what I am trying to do would be the following config:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: my-process
spec:
  schedule: "*/2 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: my-process
            image: my-image
            args:
            - my-process
            - --since=$(date -v -1H +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
            - --until=$(date -v +1H +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

When doing this, the literal string `"$(date -v -1H +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")"` would be passed in as the `--since` flag.

Is something like this possible?  If so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 11):

Note that in your `CronJob` you don't run `bash` or any other shell and `command substitution` is a shell feature and without one will not work. In your example only one command `my-process` is started in the container and as it is not a shell, it is unable to perform `command substitution`.

This one:

```
$ my-process --since=$(date -v -1H +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") --until=$(date -v +1H +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

will work properly because it is started in a `shell` so it may take advantage of shell features such as mentioned `command substitution`

One thing: `date -v -1H +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"` doesn't expand properly in `bash shell` with default `GNU/Linux` `date` implementation. Among others `-v` option is not recognized so I guess you're using it on `MacOSX` or some kind of `BSD` system. In my examples below I will use date version that works on `Debian`.

So for testing it on `GNU/Linux` it will be something like this:

`date --date='-1 hour' +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"`

For testing purpose I've tried it with simple **CronJob** from [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#creating-a-cron-job) example with some modifications:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: debian
            env:
            - name: FROM
              value: $(date --date="-1 hour" +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
            - name: TILL
              value: $(date --date="+1 hour" +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo from $(FROM) till $(TILL)
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

It works properly. Below you can see the result of `CronJob` execution:

```
$ kubectl logs hello-1569947100-xmglq
 Tue Oct  1 16:25:11 UTC 2019
 from 2019-10-01T15:25:11Z till 2019-10-01T17:25:11Z
```

Apart from the example with use of [environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#use-environment-variables-to-define-arguments) I tested it with following code:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: debian
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo from $(date --date="-1 hour" +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") till $(date --date="+1 hour" +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

and as you can see here `command substitution` also works properly:

```
$ kubectl logs hello-1569949680-fk782
Tue Oct  1 17:08:09 UTC 2019
from 2019-10-01T16:08:09Z till 2019-10-01T18:08:09Z
```

It works properly because in both examples **first** we spawn `bash shell` in our container and **subsequently** it runs other commands as simple `echo` provided as its argument. You can use your `my-process` command instead of `echo` only you'll need to provide it in one line with all its arguments, like this:

```
args:
- /bin/sh
- -c
- my-process --since=$(date -v -1H +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") --until=$(date -v +1H +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

**This example will not work** as there is no `shell` involved. `echo` command not being a shell will not be able to perform command substitution which is a shell feature:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: debian
            args:
            - /bin/echo
            - from $(date --date="-1 hour" +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") till $(date --date="+1 hour" +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

and the results will be a literal string:

```
$ kubectl logs hello-1569951180-fvghz
from $(date --date="-1 hour" +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") till $(date --date="+1 hour" +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

which is similar to your case as your command, like `echo` isn't a `shell` and it cannot perform `command substitution`.

To sum up: The solution for that is **wrapping your command as a shell argument**. In first two examples `echo` command is passed along with other commands as shell argument.

Maybe it is visible more clearly in the following example with a bit different syntax:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: debian
            command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
            args: ["FROM=$(date --date='-1 hour' +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'); TILL=$(date --date='+1 hour' +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') ;echo from $FROM till $TILL"]
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

`man bash` says:

> -c        If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string.

so `command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]` basically means *run a shell and execute following commands* which then we pass to it using `args`. In `bash` commands should be separated with semicolon `;` so they are run independently (subsequent command is executed no matter what was the result of executing previous command/commands).

In the following fragment:

```
args: ["FROM=$(date --date='-1 hour' +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'); TILL=$(date --date='+1 hour' +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') ;echo from $FROM till $TILL"]
```

we provide to `/bin/sh -c` three separate commands:

```
FROM=$(date --date='-1 hour' +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

which sets `FROM` environment variable to result of execution of `date --date='-1 hour' +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'` command,

```
TILL=$(date --date='+1 hour' +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

which sets `TILL` environment variable to result of execution of `date --date='+1 hour' +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'` command

and finally we run

```
echo from $FROM till $TILL
```

which uses both variables.

Exactly the same can be done with any other command.